# Two methods to make HTTP post call in AngularJS , which one better to use?

Tags: angularjs

Is there any good reason why should I use this type of $http post method:

```
$http.post("http://localhost:53263/api/Products/",$scope.product).
    then(function (data) { alert("success") }, function (data) { alert("error") });
```

over this method:

```
 $http({method: 'POST', 
        url: 'http://localhost:53263/api/Products/',
        data: $scope.product 
   });
```

So my question is which one is better to use? And for what purpose?

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/

Comment: Yes: it's less verbose and more readable. And a good IDE can warn you if you misspell the `post` function name, not if you misspell the 'POST' string.

Comment: well the first one has a promise, so I guess it would depend what you are trying to achieve/the scenario you are using it in.

Comment: @Michael are you asking about the usage od success and error callbacks, or about the usage of $http.post() vs $http()? Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: I think its a matter of preference, I preffered the second form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking purely between $http() (where you have to specify POST as a parameter) vs. $http.post() - then it's a matter of preference.  The $http.post is meant as a shortcut (and equivalent) to $http() with the parameters you listed.

If you are asking about the promise aspect, both of these call will return a promise.  So no matter which approach you decide to take, you can continue to append a success and error callback.

So if you use $http.post(...), you would utilize the callbacks like:
$http.post(...).success(mySuccessFn).error(myErrorFn);

Hope this helps!